# I want to show loading during working in react

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, loading

The current code displays only "Done !!!" after end work (about 3 seconds).
I want to display "Done !!!" after "Loading..." first.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [workingResult, setWorkingResult] = useState<string>();

    const runWorking = useCallback(async () => {
        // working.... (during about 3 seconds)
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < start + 3000);

        return "Done !!!";
    }, []);

    const setWorking = useCallback(async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setWorkingResult(await runWorking());
        setLoading(false);
    }, [runWorking]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setWorking();
    }, [setWorking]);

    return <div>{loading ? "Loading..." : workingResult}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use promise constructor `while` will not work because async function require function that return promise so  try this:

```
  const runWorking = () =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("done");
      }, 3000)
    );

const setWorking = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setWorkingResult(await runWorking());
    setLoading(false);
}
```

here a full working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-ishizaka-n3314?file=/src/App.js:179-304)

Comment: i tried your code before. but i get same result. i can not  view "Loading...".

Comment: I can not use setTimeout() in my real source. my work is calculating something about a few seconds.

Comment: so can you create a codesandbox demonstrating your code? so i can help you better

Comment: code is same. but real work is splitting from about 10,000 object array by some rules.

Answer (score 0):

thank you. 
i solved that.

```
const runWorking = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => { 
    let returnValue:any = [];
    // working...
    resolve(returnValue); }, 1)
 ); 

    const setWorking = async () => { 
setLoading(true); 
setWorkingResult(await runWorking()); 
setLoading(false); 
}
```